# Re-Writing a SQL Statement with a Subquery to Have a Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to re-write a SQL statement with a subquery so that it has a join for my job. So far, this is what I have.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A
WHERE TABLE_A.A_ID NOT IN
(SELECT LK.A_ID FROM Link_Table LK
LEFT JOIN Table_B B
ON B.B_ID = LK.B_ID)
```

I am really having a hard time with this. I feel like this is because of the link tables though. Can anyone give me advice on altering this query?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want a `LEFT JOin` with a `IS NULL` in the where:

```sql
SELECT {Column list} --Don't use *
FROM dbo.Table_A A
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Link_Table LK ON A.A_ID = LK.A_ID 
WHERE LK.A_ID IS NULL;
```

You don't need the reference to `Table_B` at all here.

Personally, however, I would prefer an `EXISTS`, but that is a subquery again:

```sql
SELECT {Column List}
FROM dbo.Table_A A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.Link_Table LK
                  WHERE A.A_ID = LK.A_ID);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I actually used the asterisk because I did want to see everything in all of the tables (including table B). I need all of those in order to do my task :)

Comment: `TableB` is in the subquery, it wouldn't have been exposed in the `SELECT`, @Challenge . Your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: I was trying to make it so I could see all of the data that doesn't have an A_ID matching to it. Did I just not write that query correctly then?

Comment: That *is* what it does, @Challenge , but your comment, about wanting to return columns from `Table_B` doesn't makes sense as that column is in the subquery which includes data you **explicitly** want to *exclude*.

Comment: I think that I see now. Sorry that I wasn't being clear. I have to write queries, and I don't really have access to my companies SQL Server database to help me yet. I need to add weird restrictions to them so it makes it easier for people to translate our queries into our BI tool.

Comment: @Challenge are you familiar with *accepting* an answer?